# How to Make Folder Only Accesible when User Run the Script

Tags: bash, permissions, privileges

My question is how I can make one folder accessible when script running.

In this case lets call there is bob who copying his folder by using script to specific location and there is jeff who also sharing the same group as bob also he copying his file to there with using script.

The problem is that when I set file group they need write and execute permission and when I gave to them they are able to see each other file content if they know full path of the file.

To stop that I am thinking to completely deleting all permission on folder and only giving the permission when script running and doing copying process.

But problem is that when those users run the script and script try to `chmod` the file permission they are not going to be able to because they don't have enough permission to do it. Also if I add them on `sudoers`, they are going to be able to `chmod` and change anything as they want to change.

So I am so confused about how I can make the script change permission of folder and when copying completed turn back to previous permission

Answer (score 1):

You should add a `sudoers` entry to allow `ALL` or the selected group to run a given script that does the copy to a restricted directory, with `NOPASSWD` to avoid the password prompt.

Then the users invoke

```
$ sudo /path/to/copy-to-restricted-dir files*
```

but users don't have access to restricted directory nor to `chmod`.

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem, since `sudo` will allow access to the folder using *any* script named `copy-to-restricted-dir`.